# How to create a subschema in mongoose schema that's not an array

Tags: mongoose

I have a mongoose schema with 4 subschemas within it. I been following the documetation here https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose on embedded documents

```
var scenarios = new Schema({
    title: 'String',
    type: 'String',
    description:  'String',
    authorId:  'String',
    categories:  [categoriesSchema],
    subcategories: [subcategories_schema],
    presentation: [presentations_schema],
    scripts: [scripts_schema],
    revision: 'String',
    createDate: 'String',
    updateDate: 'Date',
    active: 'Boolean',
    display:  'Boolean',
    status: [statusSchema],
    video: [video_schema],
    bundleId: [bundleSchema],
    sortOrder: 'Number'
});
```

My question is for instance if I didn't want presentation to be an array ,and only wanted to allow 1 presentation per scenario would there be a way to handle that on the schema definition?

Answer (score 1):

You can't embed Schema Objects without declaring an array, however you can define your presentation schema as plain javascript Objects (not Schema instances):

```
var presentations_schema = {
    your_field: {type: String, required: true} // etc
}
```

Then you can do:

```
presentation: presentations_schema
```

In http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html, see the meta field in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

if 'presentation' is a subschema suppose like this:

```
var presentation_schema = new Schema ({
name:{
     type: String,
     }
});
```

and you want that it should occur only once in your main schema then instead of embedding it in inside these bracket square brackets [ ] which represent an array or list you can represent it like this

presentation: presentation_schema